# Data Block Id Retrieval

Tags: linux, file, unix, filesystems, hardlink

If two files `a` and `b` are hard-linked to a data block `A`, is it possible to get the link-id or the id of the data block the files are linked to and retrieve the data without the files ?

Comment: please format your question properly next time.

Comment: If two files `a` and `b` are hard-linked to a data block `A`, is it possible to get the link-id or the id of the data block the files are linked to and retrieve the data without the files ?